# How to start Grafana on Mac?

Tags: macos, service, installation, grafana

I installed Grafana via brew:

```
brew install grafana
```

It seems that location of installation is here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/grafana/4.3.2
```

How to start Graphana service now? 
'service' command does not exist on Mac.

Tried with:

```
brew services start grafana
```

and got following error:

```
==> Tapping homebrew/services
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Failure while executing: git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services --depth=1
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/services
```

What is the proper way to start Grafana on Mac?

Comment: start grafana in a terminal first in order to see if everything is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Install grafana on Mac with Brew.

> Install and download Docker from this link - https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-for-mac/install/#download-docker-for-mac.
>
> You can launch the your terminal.
>    Install latest stable:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
$ brew install grafana
$ brew update
$ brew install grafana
```

> To start Grafana using homebrew services first make sure homebrew/services is installed.

```
$ brew tap homebrew/services
```

> Then start Grafana using:

```
  $ brew services start grafana
```

> Default login and password admin/ admin - http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to install [Homebrew services](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services):

`brew tap homebrew/services`

Otherwise the executable can be run directly at:

`/usr/local/Cellar/grafana/4.3.2/bin/grafana-server`